# JQuery Input Field clickable again after using the blur() method

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

My goal of the question is to make the input field clickable again after using the `blur()` method.
This code is based on a person list which are clickable to get the details of the person with PHP and JQuery. The PHP and MySQL querys works well.
The first request of the Database via PHP will be loaded by using the the `html(data)` to the Match-List. But on the following code, I can request the GET-Function only one time with the PHP Data inside the match-list. When I close the match-list by using the `blur()`  method and trying to click again on the input field, then the match-list won't come out again. It's an only-one time request without reloading the whole browser. How can I implement a function which renews the GET-request and loads the content again without reloading the page?

### HTML

```html
<div class="header-navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">       <li class="searchField">
        <!-- Search Field -->
            <form class="form-inline">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="searchValue" type="search" placeholder="Suche" aria-label="Search" autocomplete="off">
            </form>
        </li>
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- Where the data comes out -->
<div id="match-list">
</div>
```

### JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#searchValue').click(function(){
        $.get("./sources/models/click_match.php", function(data) {
            $('#match-list').html(data);
        });
    });
    // Hides the match-list if user clicks it outside
    $('#searchValue').blur(function(){
        $('#match-list').hide();
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#match-list` is hidden when input is blured. Data is pushed into, just element is hidden - show it on click event.

```
$('#searchValue').click(function(){
    $.get("./sources/models/click_match.php", function(data) {
        $('#match-list').show().html(data);
    });
});
```